# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined Leaflet map ArcIGS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri

I am trying to use a rest service from arcIGS, using the dynamicMapLayer property but when I add this feature the map becomes unresponsive.

```
//Add  Real map of Ireland to the maps
    var myAGSLayer = new L.esri.dynamicMapLayer("http://atlas.marine./arcgis/rest/services/Atlas/MarineAdministrativeUnits/MapServer/", {
        opacity: 1
    }).addTo(map);
```

The rest service i call fits on the map perfect but then it causes the map to become unresponsive. Is there any reason it should be doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things - one would need to post a full code example + demo to narrow it down - but a first step is that:

```
http://atlas.marine./arcgis/rest/services/Atlas/MarineAdministrativeUnits/MapServer/
```

This is not a valid URL. After the `.`, you need a TLD, like `com`.

Comment: O yes i know about the URL, because i didnt want to post the real one up as it isnt for public use, but thanks anyways